# How to make full calendar in material style?

Tags: sass, fullcalendar, materialize

I did a lot of search on google but nothing found.What to do if I am currently using `Materialize.css` framework for styling purpose.
How to change `full-calendar` buttons and other elements in materialize theme? I am also using bootstrap, so currently it is conflicting with materialize framework.

While inspecting its code I have found that `fullcalendar` is using fc-button class in all buttons.I have tried the code as below in `sass`.

```
.fc-button {
@extend .btn;
}
```

But this gives weird effect in browser.

Comment: "weird effect" is bit vague to really get any idea what the actual problem is. You mention some known conflicts related to bootstrap - I would start by removing/resolving those before you attempt anything else. Another option is that FullCalendar supports jQueryUI themes natively, so you could make one of those which looks the same as your materialize theme. Otherwise, you just have to override all the default fullCalendar CSS with whatever you need from your own theme.

Comment: A problem is better solved by showing the working demo of your error on codepen or jsfiddle. So if possible do that first.